# How can I make a Pull request using TortoiseGit

Tags: git, repository, tortoisegit

In TortoiseGit

When I hit Right Click -> Push, OK, Give it User/Pass then after that there is a Create Pull request button giving it a Start, URL, End. I am clicking, but nothing happens.

The Pull requests (0) is shown in my repo.

And one other thing, How can I make a pull request and then update it as necessary using the same software (TortoiseGit)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The doc mentions](http://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-patch.html):

> After pushing your changes to a (public) repository, you just provide other people the URL of your repository and the name of the branch or the revision id.
>   E.g.:

```
git://example.com/repo.git BRANCHNAME
```

[image: http://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/images/RequestPull.png]

- **Start**: This should be the revision on which your changes are based on.
- **URL**: The public URL to your repository, which can be access by the people who shall pull your changes.
- **End**: This should be the branch name or revision id of the end of your commits.

Once a PR is created on that public repo, you can update it (at least for GitHub) by pushing in that same branch.

I would recommend *not* using master, but a dedicated branch for that PR (here in the picture: '`issue-993`', which started from the version `origin/master`).

See "[coupe of tips for Pull Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)".

Comment: But what is he process, I mean I wanna overplay the scenario:

Someone ( Me with Tortoise GIT ) creates a pull request on:
[link]https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/Test[/link]

Then ( I reject the pull request )

Finally I amend the commit

Comment: @ДеянДобромиров just what the doc say: you push first to a dedicated branch, and then fill out the fields Start (the version from which you started your dedicated branch), repo url and end (your dedicated branch).

Comment: Again nothing
 happens ...
How do u think that I should add my Password ?
P.S. I already tried "Credential", its not working.

Comment: Do you have pushed to your remote repo first? And is your remote repo a GitHub one?

Comment: Where should I get that git://example.com/repo.git BRANCHNAME ??

Comment: git://example.com/repo.git is the url of your remote repo (it should use, I hope, https or ssh, like your own GitHub fork repo). BRANCHNAME is the name of the branch in which you did your modifications which will be part of the PR.

Comment: Start: master
URL: git://github.com/dvdvideo1234/Test.git
End: com-999

Click OK Not Valid revision com-999.

Comment: @ДеянДобромиров don't use `git://`, it was only for their example. But GitHub repo would use https or ssh: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

Comment: @ДеянДобромиров `com-999` would be the name of a local branch that you would have pushed first to your GitHub fork. Remember: your GitHuh repo needs to be a fork of another GitHub repo: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/