# How to do pull request in TortoiseGit on already pushed changes?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

The standard approach is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988891/how-can-i-make-a-pull-request-using-tortoisegit) but I've already closed the push window, so I don't have a way to click `Request pull` button.

Is there any way to create a pull request on already pushed changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just push again, Git will detect that there are no changes (if there are no changes push is idempotent) and then you can select `Request pull`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was used to do the push from `Git Sync` window and it didn't pop up any window with the `Request pull`. When I've chosen `Push...` from the context menu, the `Create pull request` was there. Thanks