# I forked a project, then push some changes, can the project owner see my update?

Tags: git, github

I forked a project from github, and today I pushed my changes. I want to be a contributor.

So, could the project owner also see my changes ?

Comment: did you make a pull request afterwards?

Comment: no, I just clicked the fork button, and then "git clone". do I need to pull ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner of the original repo won't see your changes until you [make a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/).

Remember to make it from a dedicated branch (dedicated for your changes)
See "[couples of tips for PR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)".