# how much pull request I can create at one and the same commits?

Tags: git, github, commit, pull-request

I 'm trying to understand how pull requests work. Maby somebody knows how much pull requests I can create at one and same commits? One pull or a lot?

Comment: You can make an infinite number of pull requests at one point. There is no reason you would ever do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can [create as many pull request as you want](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/) for a given branch.

But if you follow the [advises I gave on PR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309), you would isolate one specific change per branch, each branch being candidate for one PR.
That allows the integrator (owner of the original repo that you forked) to evaluate each change in isolation.