# Merge pull request in git causes the upstream branch to go ahead of origin

Tags: git, github

Terminologies:

1. The local branch is called master
2. the repository on github is called origin/master
3. And the root repository from where I have forked is called upstream/master.

Now suppose My origin/master is one commit ahead of upstream/master

So I create a pull request for upstream/master, and suppose the owner of upstream repository accepts the pull request and merges it.

This creates a +1 commit in the upstream repository with message "Pull request merged from githubuser/branchname". So now on github it shows **"This branch(origin/master) is 1 commit ahead, 1 commit behind upstream/master."**  Though actually, the code in those branches is practically the same, and they should be even.

I tried to resolve this problem by going here : [cleaning the branch without pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049650/github-fork-your-branch-is-5-commits-ahead-how-to-clean-this-without-pushing) but it seems more like a hack.

Is there any way of pushing into the upstream without making an additional commit to the upstream. **Just merging the pull request so that the upstream/master and the origin/master branches be even?**

Comment: Merge locally using `git merge --ff-only featurebranch` and then `push`. This will only work if the `master` has not diverged from your feature branch.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the code is the same. If the history is not also the same, then the branches are not the same.

Comment: @TobiasK. my problem is NOT with the local or the remote repo that I forked(the one lying in MYusername/repo is perfectly fine). It is that after my changes from my branch are added to the parent branch (remote upstream branch) since the original owner decides to ACCEPT the pull request. Then i get the message I mentioned in **bold** in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid merge-commit hell on GitHub/BitBucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358418/how-to-avoid-merge-commit-hell-on-github-bitbucket)

Comment: I just mentioned "locally" because GitHub will always create a merge-commit (`no-ff`) when merging a PR, so you can't do it cleanly on GitHub and need to push the branch from somewhere else.

Comment: @IanMiller correct, so can the history be the same? since before the pull request was accepted  **we were even (both branches were even)** , then my friend pulled it from my repo to his repo, using the pull request, now i am **1 commit ahead, 1 commit behind **

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The core of the problem lies inside GitHub.  (I'll go into detail in a moment.)  The answer to your question is thus [both no and yes](http://lotrproject.com/quotes/quote/2):

> Is there any way of pushing into the upstream without making an additional commit to the upstream. **Just merging the pull request so that the upstream/master and the origin/master branches be even?**

There are four groups of people involved here:

1. Those that program GitHub itself.  They control what appears in one's web browser, i.e., that green button you see on the page that says "Merge this pull request", which has a small dropdown arrow on the edge that, if clicked, let you select one of three types of merge.

   The three types of merge *do not* include the action you would like.  So if they *changed* this to add a fourth type of merge, or changed one of the existing three, or something along those lines, that could give everyone in group 3 the ability to do what you want.
2. Those with administrative access to the upstream repository.  They can `git push` straight to the upstream repository.  This means they can use command-line Git (not GitHub at all) to perform the action you would like, then run `git push` to update the repository on GitHub.
3. Those with write access, but *not* administrative access, to the upstream repository, through the GitHub-provided interface.  They *cannot* do what you want—at least, not until and unless the Group 1 folks add it as an option.
4. Those with no write access (presumably including yourself): they cannot do it.

Now, as to those GitHub clicky buttons—or rather, *button* singular, with three modes: the three offered modes are labeled this way:

- *Merge.*

  You might think this would do the job, but it does not, because it runs the equivalent of `git checkout branch && git merge --no-ff -m message hash`.  The *`branch`* is obvious enough, and the *`message`* part is `Merge pull request #number from repository`.  The *`hash`* part is trickier: it's the hash ID found under `refs/pull/number/head`.  This is the commit ID of the particular commit *you* submitted, through *your* clicking of the "compare and pull request" clicky buttons.

  If GitHub were to use the equivalent of `git checkout branch && git merge --ff-only hash`, with the same *`branch`* and *`hash`*, you would get just what you wanted.  Of course, there would be no commit containing the text `Merge pull request ...`.  But that would be fine.  (This is the new mode I wish they would add.  They could call it *Merge without additional commit* or *Fast-forward*, perhaps.)
- *Rebase and merge*.

  This adds the pull-request commits—there might be more than one—that are not currently on the branch, to the branch.  It runs the equivalent of `git checkout branch && git rebase --force-rebase hash` (perhaps with `--merge` or `--strategy merge` as well).  The end result is that the commits from the pull request are *copied*, not merged, to new commits with new and different hash IDs.  The merge request is completed without adding a merge commit, so there is no `Merged pull request ...` message.

  You might think that, in the case where the commit or commits to be copied are already in the correct position—i.e., just past the tip of the branch before clicking the button—GitHub would not *copy* the commits, and would instead just use them as is, as would happen if they ran the equivalent of `git rebase` *without* `--force-rebase` or `--no-ff`.  But this is not the case.  Whether there is some good (internal to GitHub) reason for this, I do not know.
- *Squash and merge.*

  This does the equivalent of `git checkout branch && git merge --no-commit --squash hash && git commit -m message`.  (The `--no-commit` here is redundant: `--squash` implies `--no-commit`.  This is an unnecessary peculiarity of the command line Git implementation of `git merge --squash`, since if you really *want* `--no-commit`, you could just specify it.)

  Because this makes a new commit that is not tied in any way to the commits whose effect is brought in, this is clearly totally unsuited to achieve what you want.

#### Summary

Those who have write access to the upstream repository can take your pull request into a Git repository on a computer they control, merge it *manually*, and push the result back to the upstream repository on GitHub.  This is what [Tobias K. refers to in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020212/merge-pull-request-in-git-causes-the-upstream-branch-to-go-ahead-of-origin#comment90990928_52020212).  That would achieve what you want.

If GitHub were to add the merge-mode I wish they would add, the users who currently merge your pull request with the Web-UI merge button would be able to do it in one step, without involving their own computers and Git command-line commands.  But without that additional mode, they cannot.

What they are actually using right now is the *Rebase and merge* mode.  We can tell because of this:

> So now on github it shows "**This branch(origin/master) is 1 commit ahead, 1 commit behind upstream/master.**"

If they were to use the *Merge* mode, you would see yourself being one commit behind, but not one commit ahead.  This would be more friendly to you, but in some ways, less nice to themselves (and perhaps other users of their repository).  When they use *Rebase and merge* they wind up copying all of your commits, so if you were *k* commits ahead before, you will suddenly be *k* ahead **and** *k* behind: the *k* that you are ahead are *your* commits, with *your* hash IDs, and the *k* that you are behind are *their copies* of your commits, with *their* hash IDs.

#### Recovering from your upstream's *Rebase and merge*

Note that you can recover from this by doing, on your own computer, the following:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout $branch
git rebase upstream/$branch
git push --force-with-lease origin $branch
```

(where `$branch` represents your branch name).  The `fetch` obtains their copies of your commits.  The `checkout` positions you for the rebase, which the `rebase` performs.<sup>1</sup>  The `git push` sends the new commits to your fork (if they are not already there) and then requests that GitHub change your fork's idea of `$branch` to point to the last such copied commit, succeeding (as if by `--force`) even if this *drops* some commits, but failing (`--force-with-lease`) if the commits being dropped are not exactly those expected.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can actually do this in one step as `git rebase` lets you check out a branch before starting the rebase, but I think it is clearer this way.  To do it in one step, use `git rebase origin/$branch $branch`.