# Why does a pull request result in the fork being behind the upstream?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

Suppose there is a GitHub repository named `upstream/project`. Let's say that I have a fork of it named `fork/project`. I commit some changes to `fork/project` and initiate a pull request to `upstream/project`. Once the pull request is accepted, why does `fork/project` become 1 commit behind `upstream/project`?

The code in the upstream repo now matches the code in my fork. Why must I pull again from the upstream repo just to end up in the same state? Couldn't the upstream repository be brought exactly in sync with the fork, rather than "overshooting" it?

I'm hoping for an answer that explains either the advantage that this system provides or the limitation that demands this workflow, whichever the case may be. Thanks!

Comment: Because of the merge commit.

Comment: @SLaks The merge commit is the situation I have described. My question is why this occurs.

Comment: @Tashus: because that's the strategy upstream chose to merge your PR. It has a couple of other options (at least for intra-repo PRs), but it chose that one.

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/52020212/1256452 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm hoping for an answer that explains either the advantage that this system provides or the limitation that demands this workflow, whichever the case may be.

If what you're really asking is this:

> why did upstream not merge with fast-forward?

Merge-commit/no-fast-forward strategy is very useful for merging PRs, because it allows **reverting** changes in just one step (because there's only one commit, regarless of how many were in the original branch). This alone is enough to make it the go-to strategy.

Comment: Excellent point, I missed that in the question indeed. Also, didn't you mean *no-fast-forward* strategy is very useful for merging PRs?

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Together you have answered my question. @RomainVALERI

Comment: @Tashus: don't forget to mark an answer, btw. Whichever you deem more helpful.

Comment: I'm in the habit of waiting 24 hours before accepting to allow everyone around the globe a chance to chime in. :)

Answer (score 1):

As hinted at by SLaks in comment, the difference is the merge commit made on `upstream/project`.

When your pull request is accepted, branches are merged and a commit is made on `upstream/project`, but `fork/project` is not aware of this before you pull again from upstream.

When you pull, `fork/project` starts by fetching that new commit, then just fast-forwards without need for a merge. Only *then* are both trees identical.

About the strategy :

The very broad picture is that merge strategy (discussed here) is more noisy and a bit clunkier in terms of tree structure because of all the merge commits. In the other hand, rebase strategy is leanier but also trickier, with nasty situations to get out of if people use it carelessly.

To go further on the "strategy" part, there are a lot of comparisons with excellent answers already, just search along the lines of "merge/rebase debate".

Comment: I suppose what they're asking is, why did _upstream_ not merge with fast-forward?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I was just getting ready to write a comment asking just that.