# Breakdown of the 3 types of Github UI merges

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

I have been using the Github UI for awhile to merge PR (pull requests), the UI looks like:

[image]

I am trying to understand how these 3 things work more carefully. Here is my best guess as what these three options do:

1. Create a merge commit

> ```
> git merge <base> <other>
> ```

2. Squash and merge

> ```
> git merge --squash <base> <other>
> ```

3. Rebase and merge

> ```
> git rebase <base> <other>
> ```

Is this accurate? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a longer version of this answer in [Merge pull request in git causes the upstream branch to go ahead of origin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52020212/1256452) but here is the shorthand equivalent.  All assume you're on the base branch to begin with, i.e., `git checkout branch`.  The *message* below is `Merge pull request #number from repository` and the *`hash`* is automatically computed from the pull request.

1. Create a merge commit

   `git merge --no-ff -m message hash`
2. Squash and merge

   `git merge --no-commit --squash hash && git commit -m message`
3. Rebase and merge

   `git rebase --force-rebase hash`

(Note that the rebase-and-merge won't function if merge conflicts occur.  It's not clear to me whether the GitHub system checks for this with `--merge` or without it, or some other way entirely.  The pull request has already checked for merge conflicts with a `git merge` with or without `--squash`; `refs/pull/head/number` always exists, but `refs/pull/merge/number` only exists if there are no such conflicts, I think.  They—GitHub—also keep track of whether the "base branch" used to create the pull request was/is up to date, but it's not quite clear precisely how they do that.)

Comment: So before each command, the base branch is checked out, right?

Comment: Well, GitHub is using plumbing code to do all the updates, there's no work-tree and no checkouts at all, but more or less, yes.

Comment: well none of these commands would work correctly unless you had the base branch checked out, right? MrCholo dares to know.

Comment: in a normal, non-bare repository, yes, you must have the correct branch checked-out to start with.

Comment: i am just curious how it would work in a "bare" repo then? do you know? is there info on this?

Comment: In a bare repository, there aren't any work-tree copies. You cannot run `git merge` or `git rebase` at all (both need a work-tree in case of merge conflicts). However, if there are not only no conflicts at all, but also no *possibility* of conflicts, `git read-tree -m` can do the merge. If this results in potential-merge-conflicts (a conflicted index), it's possible, though nontrivial, to merge individual files. Or, one could modify the Git source to have `git merge` find and handle non-conflicting changes. What, precisely, GitHub and others have done, I can't say.