# How to do a GitHub "merge branch"?

Tags: github

When I have at [Github](https://github.com/) a main (*master*) project

```
 https://github.com/MyUser/MyProject
```

and some active but non-default *branch*, listed in `MyProject/branches`, and with an URL like

```
 https://github.com/MyUser/MyProject/tree/MyBranchName
```

**how to merge (with Github interface) `MyBranchName` to *master*?**

NOTE: if really easy, only one command, how to do it by git command on terminal?

---

The result at 
    https://github.com/MyUser/MyProject/compare/MyBranchName?expand=1
is *"There isn't anything to compare"*... No more clues, no more interface to create a "merge" or "fork" or "...".

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/

Comment: @GergoErdosi ok, I see before.... But why is not simple?? I go to "Compare & review" and there are no command, no link, no clue...  Can you show the step-by-step?

Comment: Some solution in this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29184375/287948

Answer (score 2):

This only works if the branches are compatible, but that can be said as well from the command line.

Go to the branch using the branch drop down on the repository page. once you are on the branch, click the green pull request icon beside it. It will create a pull request to move all commits from your branch into your master repository.

If the branches are compatible, you should be now able to click merge.

Make sure the merge direction is right reviewing the commit history!

Comment: The branch is only a new file, is very simple, add a file to the master. The result at `https://github.com/MyUser/MyProject/compare/MyBranchName?expand=1` is *"There isn't anything to compare"*... No more clues, no more interface to create a "merge" or "fork" or "...".

Comment: are you sure the branches have any difference? maybe you didn't push some commit? you can check quite easily if the branch actually contains content that the master doesn't have, by going to the network view like so: https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/network

Comment: Yes, they are so different (!), but the intersection is empty. The *master* have one file, the `README.md`; the *branch* have many files (and no one is README). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/29184375/287948