# Create pull request for develop

Tags: git, push, pull

After pushing code to remote repository, I got such an answer from git:

```
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 406 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: Create pull request for develop:
remote: <there is my repo address>
remote: 
To <there is my repo address> develop -> develop
```

What does the part "Create pull request for .." mean?

Comment: [Hmmm](http://bit.ly/1OFvWSk)

Comment: Very nice, erip, but - no, this is not the answer.

Comment: [Hmmm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680711/how-to-do-a-github-pull-request)

Comment: erip, I know, what is pull request. The question is, why git offers me to do it?

Comment: are you sending this to some hosting service like bitbucket or github? They can use your push to add some comments. Like telling you how to create a pull request.

Comment: three, yes, BitBucket.
joran, yeah, thanks!