# GitHub: Failed to load latest commit information

Tags: git, github

I am actually new to GitHub and don't know much of its functionality. So my problem may be very fundamental. I googled, and searched in stack-overflow too. But did not find any solution.

Recently, I forked [Linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) to simply serve my curiosity. But the process was taking too much time to finish. So I pressed the "refresh" button and the process stopped. The project did appear but with a warning:

[image: Failed to load latest commit information.]

I asked for "new pull request" but this message was shown:

[image: There isn't anything to compare.]

Now, I don't understand why it happened, and if it will have any effect on the forked project. Is there any way to fix this?

---

**EDIT-1:** I forked the repository again later, & waited for the process to finish. But the result did not change.

---

**EDIT-2:** Yesterday I forked that repository again, but from my friend's account (of course with his permission). Alas! same result!

Comment: It is probably better to fork on the command-line rather than through GitHub.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forking such a large project might take quite a bit of time.
Interrupting it before completion would mean that HEAD might not have been set.

Try and delete that repo (created in your account), and fork again, this time leaving the fork process running as long as it will need.

Regarding creating a pull request, you do that from a *new* branch that you have created and pushed to your fork. See "[couple of tips for PR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)".

---

Since the issue persists, as I commented, it might be a GitHub server issue.
Meaning only GitHub support can have a look at that problem.

Comment: Thanks @VonC for your response. I did as you instructed, but the same warning is being showed.

Comment: @MinhasKamal Then it might be a GitHub server issue (as seen in https://twitter.com/jcspray/status/573869986533535744 for another project). GitHub support might know more about that warning. In the meantime, you can clone locally the original repo.

Comment: I followed the tweet & the GitHub repository, the warning does not exist now. So it was solved some how. If it really is a server issue then I have nothing to do now, I guess, rather wait. I will delete and fork the repository later, again (as you suggested).
Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: it's 2019 and same problem for linux in github still exists

Answer (score 11):

In my case, this error was caused by running an ad blocker on github. Disabling my ad blocker solved the problem.

Comment: Sheesh, same here. They must have recently added this as I'd been there thousands of times with an adblocker enabled prior with no apparent issue

Comment: Saved me quality time. Thank you!