# Github showing Not Loading latest commit information

Tags: github

Just opened Github.com and saw this message on the front.
Has anyone seen anything like this?

[Github message not loading latest commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxORN.png)

1. Strange side effect, the Github actions is not building from latest commit, but some older cached file a few commits back.
2. I don't suppose anyone know how to refresh the cache?

edit: spelllng

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub: Failed to load latest commit information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148663/github-failed-to-load-latest-commit-information)

Comment: Did you manage to understand what went wrong?