# Git:Why after Re-basing still my fork is behind the original repo master?

Tags: git, github, version-control, rebase, git-fork

I have forked a repo from Github and then created a branch named process and i have started working on this repository and i have made 7 commits with slight modifications from the original master on my branch `progress` .

Now i pushed the changes to the github and it showed me this `This branch is 7 commits ahead, 16 commits behind jwasham:master.` Now i solved this by checking out my process branch and added upstream

`$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin progress`

and then i made rebasing so my changes appear on top of those commits which were made on the original repo and done like this

`$ git pull --rebase
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded process to 266048d8326bde6f1cb137d8b898fc2fff645f94.`

But when i tried to push it to the github it showed me

```
$ git pu
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/uppusaikiran/repo_name.git
   0569dcf..266048d  process -> process
```

And clearly nothing has changed and still i have same problems `This branch is 7 commits ahead, 16 commits behind jwasham:master.`

How to approach this problem , where exactly i went wrong and how to update my fork with my changes on top of the updates?

**Simplified Question as suggested by many that question was difficult to understand**

- On Github i choose a project
- I wanted to work on , so i forked
- I cloned my fork
- Created a branch `progress`
- Started working on the branch
- Made some tiny changes without effecting any deletions [Link to what i have done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928309/how-to-make-fork-changes-reflect-with-the-master-when-updated)
- Commited and pushed to my `progress` branch
- In the mean time Owner(Original repo) updated his repo so my fork got outdated with original,but ahead by some commits which are my commits
- So This left me like this `7 commits ahead 16 commits behind jwasham:master`
- All i wanted to is align with repo commits and **also my commits should be on top of updated fork** and **these commits does not cause conflicts**

Comment: P.S : I have changed the branch name (very long to short in question) for clear understanding and convenience.

Comment: This looks like a big mess, one which I doubt I could solve without being at your computer.  But one comment: Use `git pull --rebase origin branch` and `git push origin branch` unless you know for certain that the default behavior will give you this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen nothing changed literally.

Comment: Why are you adding an upstream in the middle of things?  This seems unnecessary and possibly wrong.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen https://github.com/jwasham/google-interview-university is the main repo and i wanted to fork this repo and mark the completed topics,but due to large number of updates i need to keep my fork updated?Do you have any solution to do this in the context of the question.

After 3-4 topics completed i would mark them and commit on my fork ,but updates caused my commits to stack up and newer commits on original repo got stuck from pulling.How to rectify this?

Comment: Small question, do you have two different branches `progress` and `process` or is that a typo?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you were doing

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin progress
```

you told git that your local branch `progress` is tracking `origin/progress` thus

```
$ git pull --rebase
```

is rebasing on `origin/progress` and not on `jwasham:master` as you wish.

You need to fetch the changes from `jwasham:master` into your local clone and then you can do the rebase.

E.g:

```
$ git remote add jwasham <URL>
$ git fetch --all
$ git rebase jwasham/master
```

then you can push to your github-clone - most likely with --force if you previously published your branch.

Comment: Done this still same problem

Comment: Of course, because it is not jwasham:master. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I deleted this branch `progress` because i kind of mess things a bit and created a branch `series` and commited a small change.Now think of the repo got updated in the mean while.How to align my fork

Comment: See the second part of my answer.