# What is the return type of a failed match() in Julia?

Tags: null, julia

In the following:

```
julia> e = if false; end

julia> e

julia> f = match(r"x", "y")

julia> f

julia> a = []
0-element Array{Any,1}

julia> e == a
false

julia> e == f
true
```

...what is the type of e and f here?

Comment: Ah, got an answer elsewhere: it is type Void, value nothing, so e === f === nothing. This was not documented anywhere in the language documentation on match() and perhaps should be.

Comment: Elsewhere == discourse.julialang.org: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/what-is-the-type-of-an-empty-return-from-match/6818. Please don't double-post across the two sites.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

> if blocks also return a value... This value is simply the return
>   value of the last executed statement in the branch that was chosen

In your case, there is no executed statement, since the `if` condition evaluates to `false`. In this case, julia returns the special type `Void`, which is also bound to word `nothing`, i.e.

```
julia> typeof(nothing)
Void
```

However, even if your `if` condition evaluated to `true`, it still contains no statement to execute, and so again julia would return `nothing`, i.e.

```
julia> typeof(if true ; end)
Void
```

To get a return type other than `Void` from an `if` block, you need to execute a statement, e.g.

```
julia> typeof(if true ; 3 ; end)
Int64
```

Now, in the code you provide, you assign the output of `if false ; end` to `e` (incidentally pre julia v1.0, this is a bad idea because `e` is already used in julia for the special constant Euler's number, i.e.

```
julia> typeof(e)
Irrational{:e}

julia> e
e = 2.7182818284590...
```

That is why you get a warning message from your first line of code:

```
julia> e = if false; end
WARNING: imported binding for e overwritten in module Main
```

but julia nonetheless does what you ask and assigns the output of `if false; end` to `e`, and so now:

```
julia> typeof(e)
Void
```

Now, `nothing` is not the same thing as an empty vector. An empty vector is still a particular type, even though it has no elements:

```
julia> typeof([])
Array{Any,1}
```

so it immediately follows that:

```
julia> if false ; end == []
false
```

which is why your `e == a` returns `false`. Now let's have a look at the docs for `match`. Type `?match` at the REPL, and the first line states:

> Search for the first match of the regular expression r in s and return
>   a   RegexMatch object containing the match, or nothing if the match
>   failed

So if the regex does not find a match, then the return type is `Void` (and so return value is `nothing`). Obviously, in your case, `match(r"x", "y")` is not going to find a match, and so it returns `Void` and assigns it to `f`. Since both `e` and `f` are now `nothing` (ie of type `Void`), it immediately follows that `e == f` returns `true`, or, stated differently:

```
julia> if false ; end == match(r"x", "y")
true
```

Comment: I would change this sentence: *"the return type is `Void` (or `nothing`)"* to something like *"the return type is `Void` (or `typeof(nothing)`)"* or *"the return type is `Void` (or return value is `nothing`)"*. (BTW. julia 0.7 shows *WARNING: Base.e is deprecated, use ℯ (\euler) or Base.MathConstants.e.*)

Comment: Yes, it was the misreading of that sentence regarding nothing (which is not nothing, here, but code) that threw me off reading the documents.

Comment: @Liso Agreed. Done.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.6/stdlib/strings/#Base.match): *Search for the first match of the regular expression `r` in `s` and return a `RegexMatch` object containing the match, or nothing if the match failed.* (It could probably be change from nothing to `nothing` - thanks for pointing this out! :) BTW `nothing` is [singleton of type Void](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.6/manual/faq/#Nothingness-and-missing-values-1). You could check `match(r"x", "y") == nothing` or `match(r"x", "y") === nothing`

Edit:
More explanation in [doc](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.6/manual/strings/#Regular-Expressions-1):  *"If the regular expression does not match the given string, `match()` returns `nothing` – a special value that does not print anything at the interactive prompt. Other than not printing, it is a completely normal value and you can test for it programmatically: ...(example is here with === operator)..."*

(I don't say it is ideal now! Space for [PR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680711/how-to-do-a-github-pull-request) in this moment is probably [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/regex.jl#L182) :)