# How to contribute to a GitHub open software repository?

Tags: github

I've been reading many tutorials, trying to figure out easy steps to the workflow for contributing to a GitHub repository using GitHub itself (I'm a Windows programmer, so I find the local git CLI extremely awkward, as well as much more complicated than working entirely remotely in GitHub).

I will post the steps as I discover and develop them in the answer below.

Please, I cannot do this on my own, as I barely know what I'm doing. Suggest edits to my answer, or post comments and I will edit.

Comment: While this question is a great one, it is too vague for stack overflow. This may help point you in the right direction though https://opensource.guide as well as https://lab.github.com

Comment: I disagree. Stack Overflow is my favorite place to get answers concerning software development. I think it is the perfect place for this posting, given that it already contains many questions about how to use GitHub, and given that the answers here are sometimes better than the Help articles at GitHub. Git is a complex subject, and so far no one seems to have created an easy to use tutorial that is complete. That's my goal here.

Answer (score 2):

**Easy steps to contribute to an existing GitHub repository:**

1. If there is not already an Issue posting describing the problem or code change, create one on the GitHub repository (repo) in the Issues section.
2. Create your own GitHub account, if you do not have one.
3. Go back to the GitHub repository (repo) and click the "Fork" button. This will create a copy of the entire repo in your account as your own repo with the same repo name.
4. In your new repo on GitHub, click on the button "Branch: master". Enter a name of your new branch (include the issue number) and press Enter to create a new branch for your changes.
5. In your new repo and your new branch, click on the file you wish to edit or click the "Create new file" button. Make your changes.
6. When you are happy with your changes, scroll down to the "Commit new file" section. The title can be something like "Created file FILENAME". Add a description of your changes, including the issue number. Click "Commit new file" button to commit your change before testing it. Repeat for any additional files.
7. At the repo (Code section), click the green "Clone or download" button. Download a zip file to use locally to build if needed and test your changes locally.
8. At the repo (Code section), you should now see a notice, "Your recently pushed branches:". This means that your edits in your own repo created a "recently pushed branch". Inside this notice is a green button "Compare & pull request". Take a deep breath and push it. You will now be at the "Open a pull request" page. This will automatically request that the owner of the repo accept your changes.
9. If you see a "checklist", edit it to reflect your work so far. Otherwise, describe your changes in detail, referencing the associated Issue posting.
10. Click the green "Submit pull request" button. This posts your entry in a conversation about this request. If there are no edit conflicts, you should also see a green checkmark icon and the words "This branch has no conflicts with the base branch".
11. Wait for a response from the repo owner.
12. This is as far as I've gotten.