# "Could not find any relevant repository hosts for the currently open repository"

Tags: git, git-extensions, pull-request

I'm trying to create a pull request for the nuget git repository (which I just did a clone from). I've made a local commit.

But when I try to create the pull request I get the following error:

> Could not find any relevant repository hosts for the currently open repository

What does that mean, and how do I fix it? Do I have to fork instead of cloning? If so, what should I do now that I've made changes to the clone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pull request, especially on GitHub, supposed that you have **[forked a GitHub repo first](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo)**, and then clone that fork.

That means, of course, that you could not directly pushed back to the repo you have cloned in the first place, because you are *not* a **[collaborator](https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-add-a-collaborator)** for that repo (or you don't own that repo).
But if you want to do a pull request, it is assumed that you cannot contribute directly to the upstream repo. If you could, no pull request would be necessary.

It [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632029/could-not-find-any-relevant-repository-hosts-for-the-currently-open-repository/15632224?noredirect=1#comment22177645_15632224) the [OP jgauffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70386/jgauffin) is working with [CodePlex](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/), but the mechanism is the same for [CodePlex forks](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Forks).

If you have a clone, you can make it reference the fork by:

- [renaming origin to upstream](https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-remote): `git remote rename origin upstream`
- adding origin with a `git remote add origin url/to/your/fork`

See "[What is the difference between `origin` and `upstream` in github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257533/what-is-the-difference-between-origin-and-upstream-in-github/9257901#9257901)"

[image: fork on GitHub]

Comment: `A pull request, especially on GitHub, supposed that you have forked a GitHub repo first`. That is no necessary true, if you are member of the repo you don't need to fork it, for instance for privates repos. You should explain it better

Comment: @jgauffin looking at http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Forks, I suspect it is the same: a pull request outside of a fork doesn't make sense.