# fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, github, push, git-push

I've a repository `moodle` on my Github account which I `forked` from the official repository.

I then cloned it on my local machine. It worked fine. I created several branches (under the `master` branch). I made several commits and it worked fine.

I don't know how I'm getting the following error when I do : `git push origin master`

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How do I resolve the error without effecting my repository on Github?

I'm using `Ubuntu 12.10`

The contents of my `.git/config` after doing `cat $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/config` gives:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
[branch "MOODLE_23_STABLE"]
[branch "MOODLE_24_STABLE"]
[remote "upstream"]
    url = git://git.moodle.org/moodle.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

Comment: Please print the contents of .git/config and add here

Comment: The folder where you cloned on local machine should contain .git folder.

Comment: @xan `cat $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/config`

Comment: @pmod: Yes, I found it. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

`$HOME/.gitconfig` is your **global** config for git.
There are [three levels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063646/6309) of [config files](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

```
 cat $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/config
```

([mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637507/fatal-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository/15637954#comment22186180_15637507) by [bereal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770830/bereal)) is your *local* config, local to the repo you have cloned.

you can also type from within your repo:

```
git remote -v
```

And see if there is any remote named 'origin' listed in it.

If not, if that remote (which is created by default when cloning a repo) is missing, you can add it again:

```
git remote add origin url/to/your/fork
```

---

The OP mentions:

> Doing `git remote -v` gives:

```
upstream git://git.moodle.org/moodle.git (fetch) 
upstream git://git.moodle.org/moodle.git (push)
```

So '`origin`' is missing: the reference to *your* fork.
See "[What is the difference between `origin` and `upstream` in github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309)"

[image]

Comment: Doing `git remote -v` gives:

`upstream git://git.moodle.org/moodle.git (fetch)`
`upstream git://git.moodle.org/moodle.git (push)`

Comment: @xan 'upstream" is the repo you have forked. You are missing origin, which is your fork on github. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15632224/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309

Comment: How do I change my fork to master?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 "fork" means a repository (with multiple branch). Change to a branch is a local operation which involves git switch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309. In your own words, what does "changing a fork to master" means to you? Changing your local branch in your local cloned repository (of your remote GitHub fork)?

Comment: If you own the remote repo ghy, simply push to it: `git  push -u ghy master`.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out various mistakes I'd made and how I was picturing git incorrectly.  I made some naming errors, was avoiding clone, and did some other dumb stuff.

Answer (score 32):

I faced the same problem when I renamed my repository on GitHub. I tried to push at which point I got the error

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I had to change the URL using

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/username/newRepoName.git
```

After this all commands started working fine. You can check the change by using

```
git remote -v
```

In my case after successfull change it showed correct renamed repo in URL

```
[aniket@alok Android]$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@github.com/aniket91/TicTacToe.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@github.com/aniket91/TicTacToe.git (push)
```

Comment: "fatal: no such remote 'origin'"

Comment: @MwBakker first you have to add origin with "git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/username/newRepoName.git" and then you can check it with "git remote -v".

Answer (score 18):

It is possible the other branch you try to pull from is out of synch; so before adding and removing remote try to (if you are trying to pull from master)

```
git pull origin master
```

for me that simple call solved those error messages:

- fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
- fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and solved it by checking

```
git remote -v

git init the repo URL

git remote add origin the repo URL

git push -f origin master
```

Comment: What is new in this answer? `git remote add` is mentioned above...

Answer (score 6):

Try to create remote origin first, maybe is missing because you change name of the remote repo

git remote add origin URL_TO_YOUR_REPO

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer your question, but I faced a similar error message but due to a different reason. Allow me to make my post for the sake of information collection.

I have a git repo on a network drive. Let's call this network drive RAID. I cloned this repo on my local machine (LOCAL) and on my number crunching cluster (CRUNCHER).
For convenience I mounted the user directory of my account on CRUNCHER on my local machine. So, I can manipulate files on CRUNCHER without the need to do the work in an SSH terminal.

Today, I was modifying files in the repo on CRUNCHER via my local machine. At some point I decided to commit the files, so a did a commit. Adding the modified files and doing the commit worked as I expected, but when I called `git push` I got an error message similar to the one posted in the question.

The reason was, that I called `push` from within the repo on CRUNCHER on LOCAL. So, all paths in the config file were plain wrong.

When I realized my fault, I logged onto CRUNCHER via Terminal and was able to push the commit.

Feel free to comment if my explanation can't be understood, or you find my post superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

**100% works.**

First of first make sure that there is no hidden git folder inside your project root and delete it if there is one. Then open a command shell and execute the following commands:

```
git init -b main

git add .   //This is very important and it adds the files in the local repository and stages them for commit.

git commit -m "First commit"

git remote add origin  <REMOTE_URL>  //REMOTE_URL: the repository address in github.com 

git remote -v  //Verifies the new remote URL

git push origin main
```

and that's it. You can also read more about this in [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

My issue was related to the way I cloned the repo. Github gave a colon before the user name, for example:

```
git@github.companyname.com:usernmame/reponame.git
```

The command `git remote -v` showed this:

```
origin git@github.companyname.com:usernmame/reponame.git (fetch)
origin git@github.companyname.com:usernmame/reponame.git (push)
```

Everything matched what Github was telling me, so I was confused why I was getting following error when I tried to push a new branch upstream:

```
fatal: 'reponame' does not appear to be a git repository
```

Then I realized it was because my origin was pointing to the wrong upstream because of the colon in the URL

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.companyname.com/username/reponame.git
```

Now I can push the new branch.

**Update**

I have found that after doing this I was no longer able to push any changes. I had to reset the origin back to the URL with the colon in order pushes to work.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.companyname.com:usernmame/reponame.git
```

So I would say that this is a work around and not a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on **git pull origin branchname** when setting the remote origin as path **fs** and not **ssh** in **.git/config**:

```
fatal: '/path/to/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It was like so (this only works for users on same server of **git** that have access to git):

```
url = file:///path/to/repo.git/
```

Fixed it like so (this works on all users that have access to **git user** (ssh authorizes_keys or password)):

```
url = git@domain.com:path/to/repo.git
```

the reason I had it as a directory path was because the **git** files are on the same server.

Comment: Indeed! The `/` after domain has to be `:` if using SSH. Simply verify with `git remote -v`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and solved it by editing `.git/config` in my repo to include:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a RAM issue in the WSL. I had to restart WSL to make it work again. In the command prompt:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had a typo when running 'git remote add origin ...'