# GitHub: fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

Yellow,
I have tried setting up the option "Accessing (Pushing to) Github without username and password" following these steps...
https://medium.com/@amanze.ogbonna/accessing-pushing-to-github-without-username-and-password-3022feb077fb

But now I get an error that I can't seem to shake:

```
ficho@ficho-PS63-Modern-8M:~/Desktop/FUTSAL CUP 2020/www$ git push
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

ficho@ficho-PS63-Modern-8M:~/Desktop/FUTSAL CUP 2020/www$ git remote -v
github  https://github.com/FilipZafran/FutsalCup.git (fetch)
github  https://github.com/FilipZafran/FutsalCup.git (push)
origin  origin (fetch)
origin  origin (push)
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.4.

This is the Github repo:
https://github.com/FilipZafran/FutsalCup

Not sure what I messed up...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637507/fatal-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+%27origin%27+does+not+appear+to+be+a+git+repository

Comment: I saw that one, but I was not able to follow... I dont believe its the same issue....

Answer (score 4):

- The *origin* is a conventional default name for remote repository. It means that running *git push* will try to push commits to the origin repository.
- Look at your list of remotes. You have defined repository called *github*, while *origin* has no proper url defined.
- To fix that I would remove all remotes and add it again properly:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote remove github
git remote add origin git@github.com:FilipZafran/FutsalCup.git
```

Comment: Hey Bug Hunter,
thank you for your response. I followed your instructions, but then I tried pushing again I got new errors:

Comment: ficho@ficho-PS63-Modern-8M:~/Desktop/FUTSAL CUP 2020/www$ git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

Comment: ficho@ficho-PS63-Modern-8M:~/Desktop/FUTSAL CUP 2020/www$ git push origin mastergit@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: ficho@ficho-PS63-Modern-8M:~/Desktop/FUTSAL CUP 2020/www$ git push --set-upstream origin master
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Did you setup SSH properly? See: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey