# Every pull request to a repo that was forked from another, contains every commit since the fork

Tags: git, branch

I have a git repo we'll call RepoA.

I forked RepoA to RepoB.

Every pull request I make for RepoB contains every commit (even commits already merged into master, or commits from other people in other pull requests) since the fork.

I am not very good with GIT, but his is really frustrating.  If I can't figure this out I'm just going to delete RepoB and create a new repo without the fork to see if this fixes the problem.

Anybody know whats going on or know how to fix whats happening to me?

Comment: Are you running `git pull`? Because that will bring in the upstream changes in RepoA.

Comment: Did you fork it a long time ago? You could rebase your branch off of a more recent commit, after you've fetched the latest changes.

Comment: Are those repos public? links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every pull request I make for RepoB contains every commit (even commits already merged into master, or commits from other people in other pull requests) since the fork.

A pull request should be performed from commits done in a dedicated branch.

You should rebase that branch on top of `upstream/master` (with upstream being a reference to the original repo)
See "[What is the difference between origin and upstream in github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257533/what-is-the-difference-between-origin-and-upstream-in-github/9257901#9257901)".

[image: origin vs. upstream]

Note that if you already done a pull request from that branch, the rebase will automatically update said pull request with the new sha1 resulting of that rebase.

See "[How to do a Github pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)" for more tips.