# Push to GitHub fork takes no effect, says all commits up to date, but made some changes

Tags: git, github, git-push, pull-request

I forked a GitHub project, modified some code, and used

```
$ git push origin master
```

to push the modification to my forked project. After that, in starting a pull request, GitHub said:

> There isn't anything to compare. `nferraz:master` is up to date with all commits from `VicoWu:master`. Try switching the base for your comparison.

Vico is my name. It seems that my push takes no effect. Why is this happening?

Comment: How about `git push --all`? I wonder you're not in the `master` branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, never do a pull request from `master`.

It is a branch also used in the original repo, and it should be kept in sync [with `upstream/master`, upstream being a reference to said original repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309).

You should create a dedicated branch for the evolution you want to promote as a pull request, and push that branch to origin (your fork).

[image: Fork in GitHub]

See more with this "[couple of tips for Pull Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)".

---

If GitHub doesn't see any difference, it could because you were in a different branch , or even in a [DETACHED HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309) when you did your commits.