# Can I combine my local Github repository with WAMP localhost folder?

Tags: git, version-control, github, localhost

I have *C:\Users\my\Documents\GitHub* for my local GitHub repository, and *C:\wamp\www* is where I work on projects locally with Wampserver.

What is the appropriate setup to work with them both? Should I tell Git to use 'www' as my local repository? Will that combine localhost with Github??

Comment: use php storm to do all the above. has a nice UI for the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use the --work-tree or --git-dir argument of git in order to:

- be in the Github folder, but mention that the working tree is www

  ```
  cd C:\Users\my\Documents\GitHub
  git --work-tree=C:\wamp\www status
  ```
- or be in the www folder and mention that the git repo is in the Github one

  ```
  cd C:\wamp\www status
  git --git-dir=C:\Users\my\Documents\GitHub\.git
  ```

The other approach is to have a git repo in both, and pulling `Github` from `www`.

```
    cd C:\wamp\www status
    git add remote origin C:\Users\my\Documents\GitHub
    git pull origin master
```

Comment: Very succinct and easy even for me to understand! Thank you for providing multiple options

Comment: Would you have a preferred method in this instance?

Comment: @shipwreck I like the first one, because you get to manage only one Git repo.

Comment: Alright turns out im still confused... I want to fork a project on GitHub, clone it to my local repository, work on it with localhost, then make commits to the forked repository while also being able to merge commits from upstream to stay relevant with the initial project.

Is this how Github is used or am I totally turned around?

Comment: @shipwreck no this is fine. I meant "1 *local* repo to manage", but you can link that local repo to as many upstream as you want (like your GitHub fork, *and* the GitHub original repo). See my answer about fork at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. Love the feeling when that little lightbulb turns on

Comment: Thanks @VonC, that solution put me on the right track. But because I was using Git Bash command line on Windows, I had to change the slashes from "\" to "/" to make it work.