# Fork a Github repo into another repo as part of a larger project

Tags: git, github, git-clone, git-fork

Perhaps I'm missing something here, but I've looked and I want to do something that looks pretty simple, but I've yet to figure out (or find someone who has) how to accomplish it.

- I have a project, and I've found a Github repo that contains content I would like to use as part of it.
- I want to fork that repo's content into my project (another repo)
- I want the connection of the fork to remain in case of changes to the original file (otherwise I would've simply simply copy/pasted at the beginning -- also, I would like the option of issuing pull-requests).

I've tried to simply, `git clone https://github.com/dave/repository_of_dave.git` (and variations) but then there is still a connection with all of the content from Dave's repo. Is copy/pasting the only way to go here?

Comment: And...of course I found the answer as soon as I posted the question. In case anyone bumps into this question, the solution is found through something called 'submodules'. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) are indeed a good fit, as your repo will only record a gitlink ([special entry mode `160000`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)) to record the commit of the submodule repo you are using.

Don't forget that this submodule is a git repo of its own, which means:

- you can make commits in it (see "[true nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1979194/6309)")
- you can make it follow the latest commits of branch (see "[git submodule update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)")
- you can add remotes to it (like a remote to the original repo you have forked, in order to fetch updates from said original repo, see "[What is the difference between origin and upstream in github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309)")