# How to properly split up a GitHub project in terms of the Git history?

Tags: git

I want to break a single GitHub project into two or three new projects. Should I clone the original and have a duplicate history? Should I just start a new project and forget about the history for the new project?

Answer (score 0):

If you can isolate your projects in separate folders within your git repo, you can then split that repo per folders, keeping the history for each folder.

See "[Detach subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359424/6309)", using [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

You can then add a commit in your main GitHub project repo, referencing the new repos as **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** (as I just illustrated in "[Fork a Github repo into another repo as part of a larger project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23004273/6309)").