# Git : Files are not getting added to the staging area

Tags: git, git-bash

I have copied an external folder containing some files to my repository

[image: Added this new folder having content inside]
After that I run `git status` and it showed that in the modified files as expected

[image]

..I run the `git add .`

[image]

..it didn't show any errors. Then I run `git status` again to check if the files have been added to the staging area

[image]

Files weren't moved to the staging area. Why is it not moving this folder to the staging area? How may I move it to the staging area?

Comment: Is `jobtest`, or its files, gitignored?

Comment: Try using git add - A

Comment: @gturri no they are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jobtest` is a **[submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23004273/6309)**, not a regular folder.

You need to:

- go within `jobtest`, add, commit, push,
- *then* go back to the parent repo, add, commit and push (recording the new **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** which represents the SHA1 of the jobtest repo).

As I explained in "[Git diff says subproject is dirty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4874323/6309)", to get a clean status (ignoring the submodule state), you would need:

```
git status --ignore-submodules=dirty
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC your answer gave me the direction to look.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't remember that it `jobtest` was a repository on it's own when I copied that into this repository of my own. I didn't want it as a `submodule` so I removed `.git` folder from it to make it an ordinary folder, `add`ed and `commit`ed and that's it. It all worked.

Comment: +1. I knew jobtest was a repo, from the status message, as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are You sure that directory *jobtest* contains files, because **Git don't trac empty directories**.

I You really need empty direcotry to be tracked, add at least one file *jobtest/.gitignore* with contents:

```
*
!.gitignore
```