# How to commit clone to my GitHub as a new project?

Tags: github

After I download others' clone, how can I commit it to my github as a new project??

Answer (score 0):

If the other code is also on github I'd recommend to fork it there and then clone your fork.

If you have alredy started working on your clone you can add another [remote repository](https://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html). The original source you cloned is normally called "origin", you can name yours like you want:

```
git remote add <name-of-remote> git://github.com/user/repo.git
```

After that you can push to that repo using `-u` (set origin) parameter:

```
git push -u <name-of-remote> <branch>
```

This also works vice-versa. When you fork first, clone your fork, then your fork is called "origin", you can then add the original source as "upstream" using:

```
git remote add upstream <url-of-original-repo>
```

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/4137738)