# Failed to create a new branch from upstream

Tags: git, github

I wanted to create a new branch from upstream. What I did are

```
$ git init
$ git clone https://github.com/nalam-nmef/LearnGitWithGithubFlow.git
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/twentyTwo/LearnGitWithGithubFlow.git
```

then, to create a new branch from upstream

```
$ git checkout -b changes1 upstream/master
```

But in this point an error occurs. It says

> fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'changes1' at the same
>   time. Did you intend to checkout 'upstream/master' which can not be
>   resolved as commit?

What I will do after that is pushing that new branch to my fork

```
$ git push -u origin changes1
```

That is, I always create a branch for a new change request locally. The branch is created from the upstream/master branch. Commit changes locally and push it to my fork. Then, create a pull request to the upstream master. But, I am getting the error in `$ git checkout -b changes1 upstream/master`

Whats the wrong with this? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fetch `upstream` first.

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout -b changes1 upstream/master
```

By default, only `origin` was cloned/fetched.
Type:

```
git remote -v
```

You will see your remotes.

Ideally, `upstream` URL should *not* be the same as the `origin` one (which should be your fork).
`upstream` should refer to the original repo URL that was forked.

---

Second, don't do:

```
git init
git clone ...
```

That would clone a git repo *inside* another git repo, which is why git remote -v only shows upstream.

Try instead:

```
cd /a/path
git clone https://github.com/twentyTwo/LearnGitWithGithubFlow.git
cd LearnGitWithGithubFlow
git checkout -b changes1
```

(no need for origin/master: by default, origin/master is checked out already)

Comment: `git remote -v` is not showing the origin. It shows only the upstream. Whats the wrong here?

Comment: `upstream        https://github.com/twentyTwo/LearnGitWithGithubFlow.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/twentyTwo/LearnGitWithGithubFlow.git (push)
`

Comment: @NoorAShuvo That is because of the init/clone steps: see my edited answer.

Comment: I am sorry. I need some things to clarify. I need to checkout the new branch `changes1` from upstream. To do this, I run `git checkout -b changes1 upstream/master`, but it shows the same error `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'changes1' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'upstream/master' which can not be resolved as commit?
`

Comment: And another thing is, should I clone the repo from my origin or from upstream ?

Comment: @NoorAShuvo First, repeat the command I mention it will work. Second, upstream makes sense only if it refers an URL different from the repo you are cloning.

Comment: @NoorAShuvo By default, cloning a repo makes that repo origin. Clone your fork. go into that folder. Declare upstream there (pointing to the original repo)

Comment: Sorry again, I am cloning from `https://github.com/nalam-nmef/LearnGitWithGithubFlow.git` which is my forked repo. Updated the original question

Comment: Got it, thanks, Really appreciate it for your time. Thank again.

Answer (score 2):

So, in brief, these are the steps if you want to create a new branch from an upstream branch

- First fork the desired repo;
- Clone your forked repo
- cd in the repo
- Add upstream
- Fetch the upstream

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/forkedRepo/demoRepo.git
> cd demoRepo\
> git remote add upstream https://github.com/originalRepo/demoRepo.git
> git fetch upstream
> ```

- create a new branch from upstream

> git checkout -b newLocalBranchName upstream/fromUpstreamBranch

- Push that new branch to my fork

> git push -u origin newOriginBranchName

Comment: Yes (+1). That is what I explained 8 years earlier with https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309