# GitHub deployment from gh-pages not updating

Tags: github, deployment, github-pages

I've deployed a page using gh-pages https://dromerosalem.github.io/project-2/, I use to have a home background image that seems doesn't exist any more so I updated by changing just the image what is online url.

- Local is fine and updating with the new image
- Master branch shows new code for the background
- gh-pages branch shows new code for the background

However, the deployment page 'https://dromerosalem.github.io/project-2/' is not updated with the new background image.

**Why the deployment doesn't show my changes if gh-pages branch and master branch shows the code as I changed.**

Answer (score 1):

@VonC thank you very much for such a detailed answer. I really appreciate it.

The class `.home-body` is actually applied you can see it when you inspect it.

[image: inspector]

What is not applied is the new changes I've done in `.home-body`

`.home-body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  background-image: url(https://www.bouygues-es.com/sites/world/files/styles/image_background/public/2019-05/Mars.jpg?itok=upJry_B4);
  background-size: cover;`

Regarding your first point, I'm pretty new with the deployments and I'm still trying to understand why my colleague @IAmNini has a different kind of deployment as we notice as well I have master and gh-pages with HTML css files as you saw but she doesn't more than the bundle. Anyway she is facing the same issue than me with the background image not updating being her the upstream.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue recently, and I don't know what causes this.
Turning github pages box off and on again solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not sure why you have HTML/CSS files both in `master` and `gh-pages` of [`github.com/dromerosalem/project-2`](https://github.com/dromerosalem/project-2): you can [configure a GitHub Project Page site](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source) to get its files from the branch `gh-pages` (default) *or* branch `master`.

No need to maintain both branches: more on that below.

Second, I see in the HTML inspector of https://dromerosalem.github.io/project-2/ that the [`src/styles/style.scss#.home-body`](https://github.com/dromerosalem/project-2/blob/952c89a8ca4a9337bfe71bcadba6f52f8db77b27/src/styles/style.scss#L21-L35) is never applied:

[image: inspector]

This is never applied:

```css
.home-body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  background-image: url(https://www.bouygues-es.com/sites/world/files/styles/image_background/public/2019-05/Mars.jpg?itok=upJry_B4);
  background-size: cover;
```

That explains the lack of picture: this `.home-body` class is supposed to be generated by [`Home.js`](https://github.com/dromerosalem/project-2/blob/952c89a8ca4a9337bfe71bcadba6f52f8db77b27/src/components/Home.js#L7-L8)

```html
<div className="home-body">
  <h1>Welcome to Space!</h1>
```

The parent project [`IAmNini/project-2`](https://github.com/IAmNini/project-2) (which you have forked) has:

- a `master` branch with a [site generation in `webpack.config.js`](https://github.com/IAmNini/project-2/blob/760baa0f4f3372d8148a60b1594555ee233402df/webpack.config.js#L30-L36)
- a [`gh-pages` branch](https://github.com/IAmNini/project-2/tree/gh-pages) with the result of that generation

Its [`index.html`](https://github.com/IAmNini/project-2/blob/ca10d43428b6fd7f62619a66721f883de93a8ec4/index.html) does call [`iamnini.github.io/project-2/bundle.js`](https://iamnini.github.io/project-2/bundle.js) which includes the `.home-body` class.

As your project is organized (`master` and `gh-pages` identical in their content), your style is never called, because master never generated the right files in `gh-pages`.

Considering the parent project hes more recent commits than your fork, you might consider [updating your `master` branch with the upstream one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309), and try again.