# Codename One: test the commits on real devices before they're in the build servers

Tags: codenameone

The [Codename One Github repository](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne) is very active: at the moment, if I want to test a commit on the Simulator, I have to sync my remote fork (using [these instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984802/how-can-i-keep-my-fork-in-sync-without-adding-a-separate-remote/21131381#21131381)) and, after that, my local fork (selecting Team, Remote, Pull in Netbeans). Of course I need to change the project libraries as explained [in this tutorial](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html).

My question is if **I can test the commits also on real devices before these commits are in the build servers**.

*(Secondary but related question: every time that I compile my projects, Netbeans recompiles also the Codename One sources, with a waste of time: is it possible to avoid at all the unuseful compiling of the Codename One sources if I haven't modified them?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build from the sources from scratch but that might be a hassle. That's essential to test on iOS. If you want to test on Android there is a shortcut.

Just build a version with "Include Source" download the source bundle and replace the applicable Codename One changes into the downloaded sources.

Then follow the include source tutorial to build the app in Android Studio: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html

To disable the recompile for every run go to NetBeans preferences of your project. Select libraries and uncheck compile dependencies.